# how to use parametrized classes to reduce code base

Tags: puppet

I wrote puppet manifests and I use puppet to deploy my system.
I am now refactoring manifests in order to make it maintainable.

One of sub systems is tomcat with webapplications.
I have ~10 webapps. Each of those has almost the same procedure to deploy.
For now I use classes. 10 files - almost identical.

When I tried to use parametrized class, puppet lets me instantiate it just once.
Then I tried to create 'empty' classes which inherit from webapp class.
It does not work as well because puppet complains that parameters are not passed parent class.

I do not see any method I could abstract the code. How to do it?

I would like to achieve:

```
   node {
     class {"webapp::first": param1 = one}
     class {"webapp::second": param1 = two}   
   }
```

where first and second are applications using the same recipes.

I know there is define, but recipe is pretty big and even if it would be possible I find class more readable.

Comment: I have achieved that with define, so I have new type. I find it not intuitive. Am I wrong? Is there better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use parameters in your classes, but defines are more what you want. Quoting the official documentation

> Classes and defined types are created similarly, but they are used very differently.
>
> Defined types are used to define reusable objects which will have multiple instances on a given host, so  > they cannot include any resources that will only have one instance. For instance, multiple uses of the    > same define cannot create the same file.

see http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/language_guide.html#resource-collections

Comment: Here's a new link: http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_defined_types.html

Answer (score 0):

try to use user defined type classes are singleton by nature